# Is image size important in picturebox in Dot NET?

Tags: asp.net, image, picturebox

I am using picturebox in my asp.net project.

As I know from HTML, Image size is very important when page loading. That means that if there is an image with smaller size, loading speed is lower, otherwise higher.

Please explain As the Same is applicable asp.net too or not.

Reducing picture image is possible in ASP.net Code(C#)?.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more??? What do you exactly want from us?

Comment: I think you are asking regarding image size is affected the asp.net page loading? am I correct?

Comment: @Sagotharan I want to know whether this big sized image is affected my asp page loading or not?.

Comment: @NaveedButt  I am asking about whether this big sized image is affected my asp page loading or not?

Comment: @Muneeswaran if that is just your question? then the answer is yes. Any image having bigger size on disk is affecting your page load speed